# Enable wildcard subdomain for localhost on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, dnsmasq

I am trying to enable wildcard subdomain using dnsmasq. I followed the following link for that.

https://coderwall.com/p/6dgpsw

I am adding dns nameserver by editing /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf with the line prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;

I am using ubuntu 12.04 with wifi connection.

But this is not working for me. can anyone please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without installing the full dnsmasq package.

Create/modify the file

/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq.conf

with the line:

address=/mydomain.dev/127.0.0.1
(replace mydomain.dev with whatever you need)

and then restart network manager.

This may or may not work on versions other than 12.04

Comment: When I'm offline, this won't work, however when I'm online, this is perfectly work